# Is it possible to get JetBrains-style debug-time line hints in Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I currently have ace editor embedded in my browser. I'd like to use line hints when i run code in thr browser application. Does ace offer any such functionality, or would it be advicable to add and delete comments at the end of the line? note that I only want a single character in these hints. I also considered using the gutter in my application, but line numbers are important to me as well

[image]

here's an image of my application

[image]

I would like to have ~F appear on the green line, and ~D appear on the blue line. This is a RISC ISA executing, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: Why can't you use JetBrains product IDE instead of text editor?

Comment: @Justinas it's an editor for a custom language that I want to host online, as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways

1. hook into tokenizer to add extra token

```js
// update lines
editor.session.bgTokenizer.lines[0].push({type: "comment", value: "  // ~D "})

// hook into $tokenizeRow to add tokens after text is changed too
if (!editor.session.bgTokenizer.$tokenizeRow_orig)
     editor.session.bgTokenizer.$tokenizeRow_orig = editor.session.bgTokenizer.$tokenizeRow
editor.session.bgTokenizer.$tokenizeRow = function(row) {
    var tokens = editor.session.bgTokenizer.$tokenizeRow_orig(row)
    tokens.push({type: "comment", value: "  // ~D " + row})
    return tokens 
}

// redraw editor
editor.renderer.updateFull()
```

2. add render listener and add dom elements to the editor

```js
var dom = require("ace/lib/dom")
var annotations = {5: {text: "foo"}, 25: {text: "bar"}}
editor.renderer.on("afterRender", function() {
    editor.renderer.$textLayer.$lines.cells.forEach(function(cell) {
        if (annotations[cell.row]) {
            if (!annotations[cell.row].element)
                annotations[cell.row].element = dom.buildDom(["span", {style: "color:red"}, annotations[cell.row].text])
            cell.element.append(annotations[cell.row].element)
        }

    })
})
editor.renderer.updateText()
```

```js
var value = Array(100).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i+3).join(" ~ \n")
function isPrime(num) {
  var max = Math.sqrt(num) + 1
  for (var i = 2; i < max; i++) 
    if (num%i == 0) return false
  return true
}
var editor = ace.edit("editor", {
    value
})


var annotations = {}

editor.on("change", updateAnnotations)

function updateAnnotations() {
  clearAnnotations()
  editor.session.doc.getAllLines().forEach(function(line, lineNumber) {
    var num = parseInt(line)
    if (isPrime(num)) {
      if (isPrime(num - 2) || isPrime(num + 2)) text = " is a twin prime"
      else text = " is a prime"
      annotations[lineNumber] = {text}
    }
  })
}

function clearAnnotations() {
  for (var i in annotations) {
    if (annotations[i]?.element)
      annotations[i].element.remove()
  }
  annotations = {}
}

var dom = ace.require("ace/lib/dom")
function renderAnnotations() {
    editor.renderer.$textLayer.$lines.cells.forEach(function(cell) {
        if (annotations[cell.row]) {
            if (!annotations[cell.row].element)
                annotations[cell.row].element = dom.buildDom(["span", {style: "color:red"}, annotations[cell.row].text])
            cell.element.append(annotations[cell.row].element)
        }

    })
}

editor.renderer.on("afterRender", renderAnnotations)

updateAnnotations()
editor.renderer.updateText()
```

```html
<script src=https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js></script>

<div id="editor" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: in 2) did you mean editor.renderer or ace.renderer? In my case it gives ace as an unrecognised symbol. I replaced it with editor but it isn't working. it appends the dom element instead of the end.

1) is working fine for adding tokens, but i cant find out how to remove them. is there some documentation i could read up on?

Comment: You are right, ace was a typo. I have added a snippet for the second example. For removing tokens, you can store line numbers where you add a token and then call pop on `editor.session.bgTokenizer.lines[number]`, there is no documentation but the code should be relatively easy to read.

Comment: 1) worked for me! thanks for the input. 2 looks good too, might find some use for it later. It seems that one of my editors isnt very happy with this. When i call run, it fetches byte code and inserts it in a read-only editor, and i wanted highlighting for that editor as well. But apparently there's some time between inserting the text with valueOf(), and the bgTokenizer updating to add its lines. That's alright though, it wasn't as important as having it in the main editor.